# Replace the missing value NAN based on values of another columns (conditions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Hi I would like to fill in the NaN value based on value of sources.
I have tried the `np.select`, but this method also overwrite the other correct values.

`landline_area1['area'] = np.select(area_conditions, values)`

- Table overview

```
source  codes       area
4   1304    1304    Dover
5   1768    1768    Penrith
6   2077    NaN     NaN
7   1225    1225    Bath
8   1142    NaN     NaN
```

- conditions

```
area_conditions = [
    (landline_area1['source'].str.startswith('20')),
    (landline_area1['source'].str.startswith('23')),
    (landline_area1['source'].str.startswith('24'))]
```

- values

```
values = [
    'London',
    'Southampton / Portsmouth',
    'Coventry']
```

- Expected result

```
source  codes       area
4   1304    1304    Dover
5   1768    1768    Penrith
6   2077    NaN     London
7   1225    1225    Bath
8   1142    NaN     Sheffield
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `np.select` and adding astype str

```
#landline_area1['source'].astype(str).str.startswith('20')

s = np.select(area_conditions, values)
landline_area1['area'].fillna(pd.Series(s, index=landline_area1.index),inplace=True)
```

Comment: This works! I would like to clarify something:
1. It uses np.select to store the condition and values as an array?
2. fillna is to fill missing values

I don't quite understand the usage of pd.series - is this to locate the index?

Comment: @JamesHuang yes, that is array nor serise , so you can not fillna ~